# Matrix multiplication strange error

Tags: python, numpy

This is the problem I'm struggling from like 3 hours now ;/
In python with numpy I do simple multiplication like:

```
matrix.T * matrix
```

, where m is my matrix
but even if in my brain everything is ok ( sizes match properly) I keep on getting error message:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,20) (20,5)
```

Why is that? Doesn't 20 match 20 ? What's wrong with me ;D ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `*` operator *does not perform matrix multiplication*. On earlier versions, you need `matrix.T.dot(matrix)` or with the most recent version of Python you can use `matrix.T @ matrix`

Comment: `*` is an **element-wise** multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is the `dot` method in NumPy, or the `@` operator if you're on sufficiently recent Python and NumPy:

```
matrix.T.dot(matrix)
```

or

```
matrix.T @ matrix
```

or (if you have sufficiently recent NumPy but insufficiently recent Python)

```
np.matmul(matrix.T, matrix)
```

Note that NumPy has a `matrix` class that behaves differently, but you should **never use it**.

Answer (score 3):

Your `matrix` variable is a misnomer. What you have is a multidimensional array.

You can simply use `np.dot` to multiply your arrays:

```
matrix.T.dot(matrix)
```

If you actually had matrices created with `np.matrix`, that multiplication will work without problems